# nodejs:Socket io client Error: self signed certificate

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to connect to https socket io server by this client :

```
var io2 = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io2.connect('https://192.168.1.6:443',
  {
    reconnectionDelay: 1000,
    reconnection:true,
    reconnectionAttempts: 10,
    transports: ['websocket'],
    agent: false, 
    upgrade: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: true
  }
);


socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log("client: connect")
  socket.on('event', function (data) { });
  socket.on('disconnect', function () { });
});

socket.on('connect_failed', function () {
  console.log("client: error")
});

socket.on('connect_error', (err) => {
  console.log(err)
});
```

but when i am trying to connect i got this error:

```
$ node client.js 
Error: websocket error
    at WS.Transport.onError (/mnt/Project/NodeJs/nodejs/express-https-server-socket-master/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transport.js:68:13)
    at WebSocket.ws.onerror (/mnt/Project/NodeJs/nodejs/express-https-server-socket-master/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/websocket.js:159:10)
    at WebSocket.onError (/mnt/Project/NodeJs/nodejs/express-https-server-socket-master/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:128:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/mnt/Project/NodeJs/nodejs/express-https-server-socket-master/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:554:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3) {
  type: 'TransportError',
  description: ErrorEvent {
    target: WebSocket {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      readyState: 2,
      protocol: '',
      _binaryType: 'arraybuffer',
      _closeFrameReceived: false,
      _closeFrameSent: false,
      _closeMessage: '',
      _closeTimer: null,
      _closeCode: 1006,
      _extensions: {},
      _isServer: false,
      _receiver: null,
      _sender: null,
      _socket: null,
      url: 'wss://192.168.1.6/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket',
      _req: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    type: 'error',
    message: 'self signed certificate',
    error: Error: self signed certificate
        at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1473:34)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
        at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:916:8)
        at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:686:12) {
      code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
    }
  }
}
```

I do not want `rejectUnauthorized` be false and i want to use https socket server !!! What is problem?

I created certificate and key for socket io by this command on my linux:

> openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert

Comment: Use `rejectUnauthorized: false` instead? I know for sure you code will never accept a self-signed cert with `rejectUnauthorized:true`.

Comment: No i can not do because i want to use flutter to connect to this socket server and flutter library do not have   `rejectUnauthorized` yet, so i have to fix the problem without changing rejectUnauthorized @apsillers

Comment: Well-implemented HTTPS clients will not accept a self-signed certificate by default. Either the client implementation provides some way of turning off a signature check, or else you need to add your certificate to your operating system's global (or HTTPS implementation's local) trusted certificate store. You can do that in Socket.IO with `rejectUnauthorized: false`. I don't know anything about Flutter; maybe someone else can answer that (but do make sure you've provided enough Flutter-specific info for someone to able to do so).

Comment: I run `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0' node server.js ` but still client can not connect !! @apsillers